# Code executing if statement even though criteria not matched

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I am using Telethon to listen to new messages in a Telegram channel. It receives messages ok but when I include an if statement to run if the new message contains specific text, the statement executes each time a new message is received even though the text is not in the message.

I'm new to this and can't find an answer, so can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

```py
from telethon import TelegramClient, events, sync

@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=chat_id))
async def newMessageListener(event):
    new_message = event.message.message
    chat_id = event.chat_id
    print(chat_id)
    print(new_message)
    
    if "rain" in new_message:
          do_stuff

with client:
    client.run_until_disconnected()
```

This is the result of `dir(new_message)` (formatted for better readability):

```py
dir(new_message)
[
     '__add__',
     '__class__',
     '__contains__',
     '__delattr__',
     '__dir__',
     '__doc__',
     '__eq__',
     '__format__',
     '__ge__',
     '__getattribute__',
     '__getitem__',
     '__getnewargs__',
     '__gt__',
     '__hash__',
     '__init__',
     '__init_subclass__',
     '__iter__',
     '__le__',
     '__len__',
     '__lt__',
     '__mod__',
     '__mul__',
     '__ne__',
     '__new__',
     '__reduce__',
     '__reduce_ex__',
     '__repr__',
     '__rmod__',
     '__rmul__',
     '__setattr__',
     '__sizeof__',
     '__str__',
     '__subclasshook__',
     'capitalize',
     'casefold',
     'center',
     'count',
     'encode',
     'endswith',
     'expandtabs',
     'find',
     'format',
     'format_map',
     'index',
     'isalnum',
     'isalpha',
     'isascii',
     'isdecimal',
     'isdigit',
     'isidentifier',
     'islower',
     'isnumeric',
     'isprintable',
     'isspace',
     'istitle',
     'isupper',
     'join',
     'ljust',
     'lower',
     'lstrip',
     'maketrans',
     'partition',
     'replace',
     'rfind',
     'rindex',
     'rjust',
     'rpartition',
     'rsplit',
     'rstrip',
     'split',
     'splitlines',
     'startswith',
     'strip',
     'swapcase',
     'title',
     'translate',
     'upper',
     'zfill'
]
```

Comment: What does `print(new_message)` print?

Comment: And what does `dir(new_messages)` and `type(new_messages)` return?

Comment: @matszwecja that prints the message text

Comment: I'm asking about what exactly. Put it word for word.

Comment: @DeanMacGregor type returns string and I have edited the question to include the dir result

Comment: @matszwecja I'm test on my own channel and have sent numerous test messages. Eg "hello", "test" and messages containing the word "rain". It prints out exactly the text in the message.

Comment: that's a mystery! something like this could be helpful  to debug ```if "rain" in new_message: print(new_message.index("rain"))```

Comment: Try replacing `if "rain" in new_message` with `if "rain" in new_message.split()`.

Comment: Rather than putting `do_stuff` in your `if "rain" in new_message:` put something like `print('In if block', new_message)` and give us the result.

Comment: Is this in a try block that you haven't copied over?  You've got an async def with no await so I feel like maybe you have new_messages as a global but you should be getting an error about there being no await.